# Proper robots.txt block URL

Tags: url, robots.txt

I want to block this URL: `/services/online.html?dir=asc&limit=12&order=price` but I want to allow this one: `/services/online.html`.

I have added this on the *robots.txt*:

```
Allow: /services/online.html
Disallow: /*?dir=
```

When I try to check on the Robot Tester it is still allowed. What could be the right code for it?

Answer (score 2):

You should know that URL

```
/services/online.html?dir=asc&limit=12&order=price
```

serving the same content as

```
/services/online.html?limit=12&dir=asc&order=price
```

as

```
/services/online.html?order=price&dir=asc&limit=12
```

and so on, and so on. Position of params in query string doesn't mean anything for a web server. So disallow just query starting with

```
?dir=
```

doesn't solve all your problems. So maybe you should try something like this

```
Disallow: /services/online.html?
```

But personally I would go for canonical tags, as pointed by danielwill786. It is recommended method. You can read about it here [from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Allow: /services/online.html
> Disallow: /*?dir=
> ```

The most *specific* rule (based on the *length* of the *path* argument) wins when resolving `Allow:` / `Disallow:` conflicts - regardless of the order of the directives in the file. So, for the given URL, the first rule wins because it is the most specific *path* that matches the requested URL.

To resolve this you can either make the `Disallow:` directive more specific (ie. *longer*), for example:

```
Allow: /services/online.html
Disallow: /services/online.html?dir=
```

Or, simply remove the `Allow:` directive altogether, since *allow* is the default action. So, all you would seem to need is:

```
Disallow: /*?dir=
```

A URL of the form `/services/online.html` would be implicitly allowed since it doesn't contain a query string that starts `?dir=`.

Comment: as i can see it I could also do `Disallow: /services/*.html?dir=*` ?

Comment: Yes, you could - as mentioned, you just need to make the rule _more specific_ - there are many possibilities. But do you need the `Allow` directive at all? In the example you've given it just seems to add unnecessary complexity? The `Allow` directive is not part of the [original "standard"](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), although is supported by all the major SE's - there might be bots crawling your site that do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking forward to block URL with appearing with sorting parameters. The best thing to do is add canonical tags. It the recommended method

Coming to the above, The robots test in webmaster often takes time to update and display the new data add in live robots.txt page. Please confirm that it has been updated.

Comment: I did change the robots.txt now but on the webmaster the robots is still same and on that point that "takes time to update". . . you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There is some decent advice already in the existing answers but to answer your original question...

You could disallow all URL parameters like so if you wished:-

```
# Don't crawl URL's that contain sorting/narrowing parameters...
Disallow: *&cat=*
Disallow: *&dir=*
Disallow: *&p=*
Disallow: *&limit=*
Disallow: *&mode=*
Disallow: *&pg=*
Disallow: *&order=*
Disallow: *?cat=*
Disallow: *?dir=*
Disallow: *?p=*
Disallow: *?limit=*
Disallow: *?mode=*
Disallow: *?pg=*
Disallow: *?order=*
```

Although, it would be best to handle these in Google's Search Console where you can give Google specific instructions for each URL parameter that exists on your website.